# Animations working on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, android-bitmap

My Android app consists of a RelativeLayout in which bitmaps are dynamically created when the user clicks on the screen. Each bitmap's position is changed every 40 milliseconds by a few pixels and postInvalidate() is called to redraw the layout after updating the position of the bitmaps. The part of the code that does that is here:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        // mMoverFuture is a ScheduledFuture<?> and mFrame is the RelativeLayout
        mMoverFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mXPosition = mXPosition + 3;
                mYPosition = mYPosition + 3;

                    mFrame.postInvalidate();

            }
        }, 0, 40, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This app works perfectly on the emulators in Eclipse. However when I try to install it on my device, the bitmap is only drawn and does not move. I tried the app on a Karbonn A12 phone with Android 4.4.2 as well as a Samsung Galaxy S Duos with 4.2.2, with same results in both.

Any help on this is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I have uploaded the app onto Google Drive, so if you could test on your own devices, it would be of great help. The link is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ixhpMVEWF5QlM0MUx2eUNYdVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Karbonn device and 4.4.2 have gave me problem, too. I was trying to figure out what's wrong for 2 hours, and the same code run perfectly on all other devices. Just try once on other device.

Comment: @MysticMagic I've tried it on a Samsung Galaxy S Duos with 4.2.2 as well, but there was no difference.

Comment: @MysticMagic I have edited my question to include a link to download the app. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Doesn't work on two devices on which I tested, too.. Any other code that might be imp?

Comment: And did you try `runOnUiThread`?

Comment: @MysticMagic `runOnUiThread` results in the app not working in both the device and the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its not the answer, but you should use TranslateAnimation, its really more efficient and presented in API 11 and you are developing for >=14 as I see (for pre-3.0 you can use NineOldAndroids)

```
int nFactor=100;
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 3*nFactor, 0, 3*nFactor);
animation.setDuration(1000); // 1 sec. default is 0 ms, so fast...
animation.setFillAfter(true); //stays in place after animation
createdImageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

if you really want to do this your way you should use

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        //your stuff
        h.postDelayed(r, 40);
    }
};
h.postDelayed(r, 40);
```

and for pausing/canceling

```
h.removeCallbacks(r);
```

or for all (if you have few callbacks for one handler

```
h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```